# Add square brackets around tag name

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-badges

This post inspired by discussion on [meta.ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4546/176217) and initially was only for localization purpose on ruSO. Now I think that this idea could be useful (or at least should be discussed) for entire Stack Exchange network.

Text in the description for the tag badge in the user profile page doesn't contain any highlighting (only my own freehanded circles). E.g.:

> [image: tag badge]

Same string (I know it because of using Transifex for ruSO localization) is used on the badge's list page:

> [image: list]

and on the [badge description page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/89/tags):

> [image: description]

But for last two cases [tags] tag is highlighted as ordinary clickable link for a tag, so no extra highlighting is requered here.

My request is to add some kind of highlighting every time when tag name is used. If highlighting as clicked link is not possible, then add at least square brackets (in consistence for search pattern) around tag name.

This could also affect recently changed "Favorite/Watched tags". Current version:

> [image: currently]

Suggested view:

> [image: suggested]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This definitely should be done for reasons like readability and consistency.

First, at least have a link attached to the name of the tag like so:

> Earn at least {number here} total score for at least {other number here} community wiki answers in the [name of tag](http://www.example.com/) tag.

Then insert some characters to define the name of the tag so "tags tag" doesn't seem confusing, like `" "` or square brackets as you suggested:

> Earn at least {number here} total score for at least {other number here} community wiki answers in the ["name of tag"](http://www.example.com/) tag.
>
> Earn at least {number here} total score for at least {other number here} community wiki answers in the [[name of tag]](http://www.example.com/) tag.

The final step that makes the most sense and consistency is simply using `[tag:tag-name]` for the tag:

> Earn at least {number here} total score for at least {other number here} community wiki answers in the [name-of-tag](/questions/tagged/name-of-tag) tag.

When inspecting the HTML, the code is literally:

```
<p>Earn at least {number here} total score for at least {other number here} community wiki answers in the [tag:name-of-tag] tag.</p>
```

Instead, we could change that to:

```
<p> Earn at least {number here} total score for at least {other number here} community wiki answers in the <a href="link-to-tag.here">"name-of-tag"</a> tag. </p>
```

Comment: Mentioned raw string is `Earn at least $score$ total score for at least $answerScoreStr$ non-community wiki answers in the $tagLink$ tag` for **all** cases. So developers just need to add brackets around **$tagLink$** while parsing raw-string for text-only versions, as it's done for pages with clickable-link.

Comment: @alexolut See my edit