# Separate each tag in its own quotes

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-search, related-tags

While searching for the posts [with multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+status-completed+profile-page+linked-accounts) on the right hand side of the page you can see the "Related Tags" section:

> [image: related tags]

Is there a way to separate each tag in its own quotes like in the following picture?

> [image: suggested]

Please take a look on the related feature request: [Add square brackets around tag name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289866/339911)