# Add commas to tag list warning

Tags: feature-request, status-review, tags, error-message, grammar

Here don't say

> 'github chrome'

say

> 'github',  'chrome'

[image: Faulty tag list]

Comment: an "and" beween the second last and last entries of the list would be nice too.

Comment: @user hey, let's not ask for too much! :-D

Comment: Anyway, that's an issue with the grammar of an error message related to tags, tagged properly now.

Comment: I am reminded of a joke about a violent panda... 

Comment: I have posted several related questions long time ago: [Add square brackets around tag name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289866/add-square-brackets-around-tag-name), [Using multiple forbidden tags says about one single tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298302/using-multiple-forbidden-tags-says-about-one-single-tag), [Separate each tag in its own quotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323661/separate-each-tag-in-its-own-quotes)

Comment: One would think normally users would never see this message, because they wouldn't purposely select items not available to them. But depending on various cellphone screen sizes or typing response javascript, the initial warning might be missed. So users could still  encounter this warning. So it might as well be printed correctly. Users already feel bad "Why didn't you warn me while I was typing?"